# Ubuntu won't open (graphics card problem ? )

Tags: drivers, kernel, graphics, amd-graphics

I have recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.5 , and I can't boot it normally
It goes to an empty wallpaper screen and then it loops.

It shows the wallpaper then a black screen and again and again...For some reason I can't get into any tty (I tried ctrl + alt + f1,f2,f3 and goes on) and multiple key combinations but nothing seems to do the job.

I managed to boot ubuntu by setting on grub "nomodeset" but again this one, lowers my resolution and I can't use my second display.

I tried installing proprietary drivers from  ATI Website but I can't because of an error, I also tried from "Additional Drivers" but I can't select the fglrx driver and also tried with apt-get but throws an unmet dependency error (Which I tried to fix using -f and sudo apt-get clean commands but didnt work).

I also tried downgrading to kernels such as 3.13 and 3.16 (latest # versions) but both once they reach the login screen (I can see the login screen this time), everything freezes again....

Current kernel is : `4.4.0-38-generic` by default installed and my `lspci | grep VGA` has this output :

```
VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cypress PRO [Radeon HD 5850]
```

What should I do to fix all of this...?